# Qt Process Events processing for longer than specified

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I've hit a bit of an issue and I'm not sure what to make of it.

I'm running Qt 4.8.6, Qt creator 3.3.2, environment in Ubuntu 12.04 cross compiling to a Beaglebone Black running Debian 7 kernel 3.8.13.

The issue that I'm seeing is that this code:

```
if (qApp->hasPendingEvents())
{
    qDebug() << "pending events";
}
qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 10);
```

does not function as it should according to (at least my interpretation of) the Qt documentation. I would expect the process events loop to function for AT MOST the 10 milliseconds specified.

What happens is the qDebug statement is never printed. I would then expect that there are therefore no events to be processed, and the process events statement goes in and out very quickly. Most of the time this is the case.

What happens (not every time, but often enough) the qDebug statement is skipped, and the processEvents statement executes for somewhere between 1 and 2 seconds.

Is there some way that I can dig into what is happening in the process events and find out what is causing the delay?

Comment: I don't see the rest of your code, but it looks like you're writing pseudosynchronous spaghetti code, and somewhere else in your code this might be biting you back. You're executing an operation somewhere that blocks for these 1-2 seconds. When you re-enter the event loop, any existing timeouts are ignored, so if this `processEvents` calls your code that calls `processEvents` again, you're in trouble. Generally speaking, you can write clean, asynchronous code without any `processEvents` calls.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you wish to regain control after a given time, you should use a timer for that. You won't be then fighting with reentrancy issues, or with system events whose processing takes "too long" - or, at least, you'll be doing the most you can do to keep your code in control as early as desired.

Answer (score 0):

> Qt is processing events for longer than specified for `QApplication::processEvents` call on Linux
>   system. Is there some way that I can dig into what is happening in the
>   process events and find out what is causing the delay?

Yes, observing Qt source code may help. The source code is in `/home/myname/software/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_unix.cpp` or maybe somewhere around that:

```
bool QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags)
{
    Q_D(QEventDispatcherUNIX);
    d->interrupt.store(0);

    // we are awake, broadcast it
    emit awake();

    // This statement implies forcing events from system event queue
    // to be processed now with doSelect below
    QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(0, 0, d->threadData);

    int nevents = 0;
    const bool canWait = (d->threadData->canWaitLocked()
                          && !d->interrupt.load()
                          && (flags & QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents));

    if (canWait)
        emit aboutToBlock();

    if (!d->interrupt.load()) {
        // return the maximum time we can wait for an event.
        timespec *tm = 0;
        timespec wait_tm = { 0l, 0l };
        if (!(flags & QEventLoop::X11ExcludeTimers)) {
            if (d->timerList.timerWait(wait_tm))
                tm = &wait_tm;
        }

        if (!canWait) {
            if (!tm)
                tm = &wait_tm;

            // no time to wait
            tm->tv_sec  = 0l;
            tm->tv_nsec = 0l;
        }
        // runs actual event loop with POSIX select
        nevents = d->doSelect(flags, tm);
```

It seems there system posted events that are not accounted for `qApp->hasPendingEvents()`. And then `QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(0, 0, d->threadData);` flushes those events to be processed by `d->doSelect`. If I was solving this task I would try to either flush those posted events *out* or maybe realize if and why `flags` parameter has `QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents` bit set. I usually either build Qt from source code or provide debugger with the path to its symbols/source so it is possible to dig in there.

P.S. I glanced at Qt 5.5.1 source event processing code but that should be very similar to what you deal with. Or could that implementation actually be `bool QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags)`? It is easy to find on an actual system.